# Organizing .xhtml files in subfolders

Tags: facelets, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2.0 project wiht lots of .xhtml files. Due to a security filter I want to put some of the files in a /secure folder to then aply the filter on.

I tried simply moving the files to a folder. But then I get an exception

"/selectRole.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource"

Do I need to add something to the faces-config or web.xml?

Comment: Which security filter do you use ? In case of spring-security you should check application-context.xml as well.

Comment: I have built my own and I the filter I'm making a redirect

res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
res.setHeader("Location", baseURI + "selectRolej.xhtml" + ");
res.flushBuffer();

Answer (score 1):

Your application is trying to read `/selectRole.xhtml` from a bean, or redirect action.

In JSF2, the navigation rules are written in the beans. The return String of the method, may return the location of the file relatively to WebContent folder.

**EDIT:**
Please note, that it may appear also in `faces-config.xml` file, though is not recommended.

Look where you have declared it, (usually in the bean file that redirects to it) and change it to return `"/secure/selectRole"`

For example:

```
Public class myBean{
  public String save(){
    return "/secure/selectRole";
   }
}
```

Another place where I can think of, is in another .xhtml file - where in h:link you link to this page.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The trick is that I have not yet called anything in a bean. The first thing that happends is that I redirect the request to a xhtmlpage in a servletfilter. I have changed the URL there. What loads the externat context. It seams to skip loading the subfolder.