# Separating .xhtml in subfolders

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm using JSF for my project and I want to separate .xhtml files in subfolders.

My current directory structure is as follows:

```
webapp/
    resources/
    WEB-INF/ (beans.xml, web.xml)
    faces/ (test.xhtml)
    login.xhtml
    register.xhtml
...
```

But when I try to access [PROJECT]/faces/test.xhtml it never works. I get a 404 Not Found error with the following description: "/test.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource."

The stackOverflow question: [Organizing .xhtml files in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440538/organizing-xhtml-files-in-subfolders) has exactly the same problem and still hasn't received any helpful answers regarding this problem.

As an alternative I can also ofcourse use **container managed authentication**, but I refuse to do so, because it should be possible to just separate views in different subfolders, right?

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>timeline.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okayy I solved my problem by removing the following line of code:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I don't know why that was a problem though.

Comment: The `/faces/*` url pattern is a prefix written to the url which does not yield a subfolder is searched for the source file. If the above mapping is configured, `/faces/something/some.xhtml` will search for `/webapp/something/some.xhtml`. If you remove this configuration, default servlet mappings `*.jsf` and `*.xhtml` are configured automatically. Therefor `/faces/something/some.xhtml` would search for `/webapp/faces/something/some.xhtml`

Comment: @Selaron, thank you for the answer! It  is a lot more clear to me now. This says to me that it also works if you browse to`/faces/faces/some.xhtml`, but it doesn't.